# AjaxFileUpload temp data saved to wrong account when multiple users uploading to Database simultaneously

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm using an Ajax File Upload control (Ajax Control Toolkit) in an ASP.Net application on an IIS server. There may be dozens of users uploading files at the same time (within seconds apart). Per the [AjaxFileUpload documentation](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.net/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx), these files are temporarily stored on the server and deleted when  `e.DeleteTemporaryData();` is called. If multiple users are trying to upload documents simultaneously, random files are getting stored in the database to the wrong account. Calling the delete method does not seem to help. Is this a bug? How can I prevent the mismatch of data? Each account has a unique account number and the files are inserted into a SQL Database.

```
protected void DocumentA_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            //static fields
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(appID))
            {
                applicationID = appID;
            }


            string ext = Path.GetExtension(e.FileName);


            if (contenttype != String.Empty)
            {
                byte[] bytes = e.GetContents();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.spUploadAttachments", ConnC.con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@ApplicationID",
                        Value = applicationID
                    });
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@FileName",
                        Value = e.FileName
                    });
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@FileContent",
                        Value = bytes
                    });
                    ConnC.con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    ConnC.con.Close();
                }
            }
            e.DeleteTemporaryData(); //Thought this would clear up the temp data and prevent mismatch but doesn't seem to help.
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //exception logic here
        }
    }
```

Comment: And are you not use the "save as" event that triggers here? I never heard of someone looking at, or using or hoping that the temporalty files are to be used here? The aj fileuploader has 3 events that triggers server side. (start upload - not much use), one file complete up-loaded - THIS event is where you supposed to execute the save-as and  put the file and save it where you want - and this means each user should not be tripping over each other. I mean, I have ZERO clue as to what some temp file is, but you MOST certainly are to use the file uploaded complete event and execute a save-as.

Comment: Darn - scrolling missed the first line of your code. Ok, so you putting the file name in the database - but I don't see where you are putting the up-loaded file in that event? you want (quite much have to) execute a .SaveAs to put the file name some place. You can't just leave the file in temp storage - that file name in temp storage could be anything and is really out of your control. so don't use or assume or rely on the temp storage location for the file - it is ONLY for up-loading process. You REALLY need to execute a         AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs("my file name") in that complete event.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I did exclude the bit of code (for brevity) that inserts the actual file. I'll add it (for clarity :)) How do I execute a .SaveAs - this will be stored in the db? Thanks.

Comment: Well, as noted, your code puts a row in a table, but now you need/want to save the file also in the database - you code does/did no such thing. I have to put this in a answer - but yes I always done a save as in the file complete event, but it DOES look like you can use getfilecontents and myabe you dno't have to use save-as.

Comment: Ah, ok  - my bad. you ARE using getfile contents. Ok, then this really should work. The only issue then is appID - it looks to be some static class - and that will be shared by all users. So are the files being saved ok, but ONLY the appID is messing up?

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I believe you may have hinted to the issue. I wasn't aware that using a static class for a random generated appID would be shared by all users. Yes, the files are saving in the database but if Floyd selects a file and so does Ellie - if Ellie clicks upload first, Ellie will see Floyds file in the database under her appID. It's very strange but perhaps the static class is the culprit! I tried using a Session variable and it seems to work but some devices do not support Session state so that's why I went with a static class.

Comment: Viewstate can't be used (it is browser state - and nor is the web page avaible in that file complete up-load event. Your only real choice is session(). Since session is 100% server based, then what client machine browser used should not matter.Session() is global per user. (can be some issue if one user has two tabs open to up-load, but in most cases not a issue).  So controls on page - not available. ViewState - not available. This quite much leaves you with session(), and of course say Membership.GetUser.ProviderUserKey (if you using FBA authentication).

Comment: Just a a FYI = all devices no mater what should support session(). Viewstate might not be, but session() for sure is ok with everything.